# What ships were used for rum-running?

Tags: 1920s, prohibition, ships

So I'm writing a novel taking place during the Prohibition Era, and although I've got the basics down, I'm curious as to whether anybody knows any specifics to how rum-running worked.

What kind of ships were commonly used for transporting alcohol? Also, how long would a trip take?

Any information would help, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: What do you know already? What do you need to know that Google doesn't reveal with a [simple search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rum+runner+vessels&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjel8-5q7_YAhXBIcAKHdq2CJ4QsAQIRQ&biw=1920&bih=947#imgrc=holpzteFne2kLM:)?

Comment: In Windsor Ontario it was apparently possible to simply walk across Lake St. Clair in various places. See also [Go-Fast-Boat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-fast_boat)

Comment: In his biography of Sam Bronfman, Pierre Berton stated something like: "The legislative acts of the United States and Canada could not have been deliberately crafted to maximize the profits of the Bronfmans further than they actually did."

Comment: "how long would a trip take?" - depends where from / to. This question looks too broad and needs more detail, but the OP should be given time to edit.

Comment: I don't think asking for common ship types is too broad, but obviously the time it takes is going to be very location dependent. I suggest you pick a specific place (e.g. your novel's setting) to ask about, which would probably produce more relevant answers overall. @LarsBosteen Note that the OP can always edit a question that has been put on hold, and then nominate the question for re-opening.

Comment: From what I understand, most liquour smuggling took place by land, across the Canadian border.

Comment: I knew a "rum runner" who was a commercial fisherman who lived near Monroe, on Lake Erie.  He would put cases of Canadian whiskey in the bottom of his fishing boat, a 30 foot trawler, in the summer, and would drive across the ice in the winter.  His favorite story was about the 1932 Chevy that broke through the ice one day; he said it had many cases of whiskey aboard when it sank out of sight!